# how to benchmark multi-query motion planners in Moveit?

Tags: ros, rrt, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have used benchmark in movei for single query.
now i want to compare PRM with RRT. how can we define multi-query?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312827/how-to-benchmark-multi-query-motion-planners-in-moveit!?/) by [MahShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/37854/mahshah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day,

you can use the benchmarking tool to compare both planners in single query applications.

PRM constructs a graph-structure (roadmap) of the free configuration space. Instead of exploring the c space every time you plan a path like RRT does, PRM is able to use the generated roadmap of the first query.

I found [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1026) Issue (Nr. 1026) on Github. Also, there is [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/328726/moveit-motion-planning-reuse/) post about the same topic.

It seems that the reusability of roadmaps generated by planning algorithms like PRM is not yet implemented in MoveIt.

---

Originally posted by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) with karma: 35 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0